# What is a UVC device and how does it work without drivers?

Tags: linux, drivers, video, recording

I searched for video recording equipment to use with Linux. Upon searching I find some products that state that they do not come with drivers because it is a UVC device. Assuming that other products that do come with a driver are for Windows only, I purchased one labeled no driver and it worked just fine without any tinkering. How do these so called UVC devices work without drivers?

Answer (score 0):

They don’t work without drivers, they work without a device-*specific* driver. They do so by implementing a common standard, [USB video class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_video_device_class) (UVC). The standard describes how a device should identify itself, expose the features it supports, and how it should implement those features. Any device which meets the specification will work on any system with an existing UVC driver.

This is the same principle as that behind USB mice, storage devices etc. that work without device-specific drivers (or at least, provide a common set of features without device-specific drivers).